# Flask issue with button on/off

Tags: python, flask, button

I am developing a web interface with flask where the user can enter values in a form and then send the value via http server. After that, I collect the values and send them to a server OPC-UA connected with a motor supposed to rotate.

I want to fill up a form and then save the values by clicking a Submit button. But I also want to create another button which when I click on it fill automatically the form with default values (in my case, I want 0 everywhere). This second button is a button "ON/OFF". At the beginning, the button is 'Off' which means we have to send the value 0 (motor are not rotating when we send angle=0, speed=0...).
Then when it's ON I can send values.

The button Submit is working well and is sending correctly the selected value from the user.

However, I don't know why the other button is not working. Whenever I click on it, nothing happens, no error message.

Here is my code:

```
# sends data from html form to database
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html',drive_state='Off') 


function_id = 0
angle = 0
speed = 0

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_parameters():
    if request.form.get("submit"):
        function_id = request.form['function_id']
        angle = request.form['angle']
        speed = request.form['speed']  
        opc_state = 1
        print(function_id)
        print(angle)
        print(speed)
        # drive_state=request.form['drive_state'] 
    if request.form.get("turn_on"):
        function_id = 0
        angle = 0
        speed = 0
        # call opcua func    
        # opcua_state = opc_read
        opc_state = 0
        if opc_state == 0:
            drive_state = 'Off'
            opc_state = 1
        if opc_state == 1:
            drive_state = 'On'
            opc_state = 0

    # return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('form.html', function_id=function_id, angle=angle, speed=speed)
# get_parameters()
# print(form_params)
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample page to test fill_web_form.py</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p1><strong>SAMPLE PAGE TO TEST FILL_WEB_FORM.PY</strong></p1>

    <!--test form-->
    <form method="post" action="/">
        Test the motor:<br>
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Function number: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="function_id" value={{function_id}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Angle: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="angle" value={{angle}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Speed: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="speed" value={{speed}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <input type="button" name="drive_state" Value={{drive_state}}> </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The user interface looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood well but I think for you it's easier do some javascript functionality at the Off button and once you click it it populate all the field with default value "0" and then you save it. Otherwise I advice you to have 2 different end-point and use for the OFF button a GET API.

Comment: yes but i have to code it in python...

Comment: so create another API (GET) on OFF button that return you the default value and with that you populate the UI; it's just a second endpoint on the same Flask app

Comment: create two `<form>` - first with all `input` and `submit` and second only with `OFF`

Comment: your second button doesn't work because it has name `name="drive_state"` but you check name `if request.form.get("turn_on"):`. You simply use two different names. You have to check `if request.form.get("drive_state"):` but you should put this button on separated `<form>` to send this value only when you press it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few problems.

First. Second button has name `name="drive_state"` but you check name

```
if request.form.get("turn_on"):
```

You have to check

```
if request.form.get("drive_state"):
```

But it has to be `type="submit"` to send to server.

```
 <input type="submit" name="drive_state" Value={{drive_state}}>
```

---

Other problem are local variables in function which are deleted between requests. You have to use `global` to inform function that it has to keep it in global variables so they will be not deleted.

---

Another problem. If you run

```
    if opc_state == 0:
        #... code ...
        opc_state = 1

    if opc_state == 1:
        # ... code ...
        opc_state = 0
```

then first `if` will set `opc_state = 1` but next it will run second `if` which will set it back to `opc_state = 0`. You have to use `elif` or else

```
    if opc_state == 0:
        #... code ...
        opc_state = 1

    #elif opc_state == 1:
    else:
        # ... code ...
        opc_state = 0
```

---

And you forgot to send `drive_state` to template

---

Minimal working code with HTML directly in code so everyone can simply copy it and run it.

```
html = '''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample page to test fill_web_form.py</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p1><strong>SAMPLE PAGE TO TEST FILL_WEB_FORM.PY</strong></p1>

    <!--test form-->
    <form method="post" action="/">
        Test the motor:<br>
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Function number: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="function_id" value={{function_id}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Angle: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="angle" value={{angle}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> Speed: </td> 
                <td> <input type="text" name="speed" value={{speed}}> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"> </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <input type="submit" name="drive_state" Value={{drive_state}}> </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>'''

# sends data from html form to database
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template_string(html, drive_state='Off') 

function_id = 0
angle = 0
speed = 0
drive_state = 'Off'
opc_state = 0

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_parameters():
    global function_id
    global angle
    global speed
    global drive_state
    global opc_state
    
    if request.form.get("submit"):
        function_id = request.form['function_id']
        angle = request.form['angle']
        speed = request.form['speed']  
        opc_state = 1
        print('function_id:', function_id)
        print('angle:', angle)
        print('speed:', speed)

    if request.form.get("drive_state"):
        function_id = 0
        angle = 0
        speed = 0
        # call opcua func    
        # opcua_state = opc_read
        #opc_state = 0
        
        if opc_state == 0:
            drive_state = 'Off'
            opc_state = 1
        elif opc_state == 1:  # it has to be `else`
            drive_state = 'On'
            opc_state = 0
        print('drive_state:', drive_state)

    # return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template_string(html, function_id=function_id, angle=angle, speed=speed, drive_state=drive_state)

app.run()
```